# Erratic display from RecyclerView when item deleted. Android Studio and cloud Firestore

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a delete item button placed in a card view within a recycler view. When I press to delete, the item seems to recreate it's self briefly then disappear. However when click out and then back in to the recyclerView activity, the item has re-created itself in the view but not the database. I think the issue must be in the deleteButton onClickListener, but I cannot seem to find a solution to the problem...Any advice would be great. I've included the recycler adapter code and the code for the activity that displays the cardView. Also the xml in case its something to do with the onClick method that can be set there.

**UserMenuListAdapter.java**

```
import static com.melcolton.bite.UsersMenuActivity.finalId;

public class UserMenuListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserMenuListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "Adapter Log";
private View.OnClickListener myClickListener;
private FirebaseFirestore fbFirestore;
private FirebaseAuth fbAuth;

public String fbUserId;
public List<UserMenu> userMenu;
public Context context;

public UserMenuListAdapter(Context context, List<UserMenu> userMenu, View.OnClickListener myClickListener) {
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    this.userMenu =  userMenu ;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserMenuListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    Context context = parent.getContext();
    View menuView = LayoutInflater.from( context ).inflate( R.layout.item_confirm_list_element, parent, false );
    return new ViewHolder( menuView, myClickListener );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserMenuListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fbFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    fbUserId = fbAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = holder;

        holder.userMenuName.setText( userMenu.get( position ).getItemName() );
        holder.userMenuDesc.setText( userMenu.get( position ).getItemDesc() );
        holder.userMenuCals.setText( userMenu.get( position ).getItemCals().toString() );
        holder.userMenuCost.setText( userMenu.get( position ).getItemCost().toString() );

        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText( context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


                fbFirestore.collection( "AppUsers" ).document(fbUserId).collection( "UserMenu" ).document(finalId)
                        .delete().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        userMenu.remove( position );
                        notifyItemRemoved( position );
                        notifyItemRangeChanged( position, userMenu.size() );
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //holder.menuView.setVisibility( View.GONE );

                    }
                } );

            }

        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return userMenu.size();
}

public void onEvent (QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e !=null) {
        Log.w( TAG, "onEvent error: ",e );
        onError (e);
    }
}

private void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    Log.w( TAG, "onEvent error: ",e );
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CardView userMenuCardView;
    public TextView userMenuName;
    public TextView userMenuDesc;
    public TextView userMenuCals;
    public TextView userMenuCost;
    public Button deleteButton;
    View menuView;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView, View.OnClickListener myClickListener) {
        super( itemView );
        itemView.setOnClickListener( myClickListener );
        menuView = itemView;

        userMenuCardView = menuView.findViewById( R.id.user_menu_cardview );
        userMenuName = menuView.findViewById( R.id.txt_cart_item_name );
        userMenuDesc = menuView.findViewById( R.id.txt_cart_item_desc );
        userMenuCals = menuView.findViewById( R.id.txt_cart_item_cals );
        userMenuCost = menuView.findViewById( R.id.txt_cart_item_cost );
        deleteButton = menuView.findViewById( R.id.remove_button );
    }
}
}
```

**UsersMenuActivity.java**

```
import static com.melcolton.bite.ChooseRestaurant.valFromAct1;

public class UsersMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "UserMenuActivity";
public static String finalId;
public Context umContext;
public Button myButton;
public static int totalCalsSet;
public static double totalCostSet;
public TextView caloriesUsed;
public String toCalsUsed;

Toolbar menuToolbar;
private FirebaseFirestore umFirestore;
private FirebaseAuth umFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private RecyclerView umRecyclerView;
private List<UserMenu> userMenu;
private View.OnClickListener umClickListener;
private UserMenuListAdapter userMenuListAdapter;
private String getUserId;
private TextView passedCalContent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_users_menu );

    menuToolbar = findViewById( R.id.menu_toolbar );
    setSupportActionBar( menuToolbar );

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( false );
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled( false );
    }

    myButton = findViewById( R.id.remove_button );

    caloriesUsed = findViewById( R.id.users_menu_calories_used );
    toCalsUsed = Integer.toString( totalCalsSet );
    caloriesUsed.setText( toCalsUsed );

    userMenu = new ArrayList<>();
    userMenuListAdapter = new UserMenuListAdapter( getApplicationContext(), userMenu, umClickListener );

    umRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById( R.id.user_menu_recycler_view );
    umRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );
    umRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( this ) );
    umRecyclerView.setAdapter( userMenuListAdapter );

    passedCalContent = findViewById( R.id.users_menu_calories_set );
    passedCalContent.setText( valFromAct1 );

    umFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    umFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    getUserId = Objects.requireNonNull( umFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() ).getUid();


    CollectionReference userMenuRef = umFirestore.collection( "AppUsers" )
            .document( getUserId )
            .collection( "UserMenu" );
    userMenuRef.limit( 100 ).addSnapshotListener( (documentSnapshots, e) -> {

        if (e != null) {
            Log.d( TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage() );

        }
        assert documentSnapshots != null;
        for (DocumentChange doc : Objects.requireNonNull( documentSnapshots ).getDocumentChanges()) {
            UserMenu menu = doc.getDocument().toObject( UserMenu.class ).withId( doc.getDocument().getId() );

            Log.d( TAG, doc.getDocument().getId() + " => " + doc.getDocument() );

            finalId = doc.getDocument().getId();
            userMenu.add( menu );
            userMenuListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } );


//Method here to calculate the total cals value to show in header.

    userMenuRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                int totalCals = 0;
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    double itemCals = document.getDouble("itemCals");
                    totalCals = (int) (totalCals + itemCals);
                }
                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(totalCals));

                totalCalsSet = totalCals;
            }
        }

    });

 //Calculates the total cost of the menu.

    userMenuRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                double totalCost = 0;
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    double itemCost = document.getDouble("itemCost");
                    totalCost = totalCost + itemCost;
                }
                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(totalCost));

                totalCostSet = totalCost;
            }
        }

    });



}


//ACTION BAR
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main_menu, menu );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_logout_button:
            logout();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_settings_button:
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent( UsersMenuActivity.this,     AccSetupActivity.class );
            startActivity( settingsIntent );
            return true;

        case R.id.about_info:
            Intent aboutIntent = new Intent( UsersMenuActivity.this, DisclaimerActivity.class );
            startActivity( aboutIntent );
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }

}

private void sendToLogin() {

    Intent loginIntent = new Intent( UsersMenuActivity.this,     LogInActivity.class );
    startActivity( loginIntent );

}

private void logout() {
    mAuth.signOut();
    sendToLogin();
    finish();

}
}
```

**Layout Files**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/food_constraint_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/user_menu_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_cart_item_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="title of item"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_cart_item_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_cart_item_name"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_cart_item_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calories_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_cart_item_desc"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Calories"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/devider" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cost_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_cart_item_desc"
            android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txt_cart_item_cost"
            android:text="Cost   £"
            android:textSize="12sp"

                   app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/txt_cart_item_cals"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_cart_item_cals" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_cart_item_cals"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txt_cart_item_name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_cart_item_desc"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:text="100"
            android:textColor="@color/biteBlue"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/calories_text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/calories_text" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_cart_item_cost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/calories_text"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="4.99"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/cost_text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cost_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/devider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_cart_item_cals"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/biteBlue"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_cart_item_desc" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/remove_button"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/devider"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textColor="@color/biteBlue"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_cart_item_desc" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the onCreate method of the adapter. Removing the cast to UserMenuListAdapter and simply having ViewHolder onCreate... has stopped the issue.

```
@NonNull
```

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

```
Context context = parent.getContext();
View menuView = LayoutInflater.from( context ).inflate( R.layout.item_confirm_list_element, parent, false );
return new ViewHolder( menuView, myClickListener );
```